# Crashlytics says "Received null settings, skipping report submission"

Tags: crashlytics, firebase-crash-reporting, crashlytics-android

I am trying to switch from Firebase Crash reporting to Firebase Crashlytics.

I have followed the guide here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/upgrade-from-crash-reporting

But during initialization the logs says:

> Received null settings, skipping report submission!

And then when testing crashes:

> Cannot send reports. Settings are unavailable.

Network connection is good, so no reason why it can't get settings.

Log output:

```
D/CrashlyticsCore: Initialization marker file created.
W/CrashlyticsCore: Received null settings, skipping report submission!
D/CrashlyticsCore: Initialization marker file removed: true
D/CrashlyticsCore: Crashlytics is handling uncaught exception "java.lang.RuntimeException: Testing crash" from thread main
D/CrashlyticsCore: Logging Crashlytics event to Firebase
D/CrashlyticsCore: No log data to include with this event.
D/CrashlyticsCore: Unable to close session. Settings are not loaded.
D/CrashlyticsCore: Opening a new session with ID 5A042DD20217-0002-4F33-A5AF620D03D1
D/Fabric: Falling back to Crashlytics key lookup from Manifest
D/Fabric: Falling back to Crashlytics key lookup from Strings
D/Fabric: Falling back to Crashlytics key lookup from Manifest
D/Fabric: Falling back to Crashlytics key lookup from Strings
W/CrashlyticsCore: Cannot send reports. Settings are unavailable.
D/CrashlyticsCore: Crashlytics completed exception processing. Invoking default exception handler.
```

Comment: Mike from Firebase and Fabric here. Did you click on the button in your Firebase dashboard saying that you want to get Crashlytics?

Comment: No, I don't see a button. I saw a message about Crash Reporting would be replaced by Crashlytics about a month ago. But I don't remember if that message had a button.

Comment: @MikeBonnell Should I wait until Crashlytics becomes the primary crash tool in Firebase? Or can I activate it in any way?

Comment: Gotcha, if you don't see Crashlytics in the Firebase sidebar, then you'll need to opt-in to enable it: https://g.co/firebase/opt-in It's still being rolled out to more users.

Comment: I never saw a button either. I already had Crashlytics showing in the Firebase sidebar, and already had the update to the firebase dashboard, and was experiencing the same problem (Cannot send reports). But going to the optin link g.co/firebase/opt-in and actually opting-in solved the problem for me.

Comment: Hi @MikeBonnell: I have already opt-in for Firebase Crashlytics and I can see crashes for debug build, however for my release builds i cant see anything. I tried with/without proguard but any change and I have the same error as Claus. Dont know where to look

Comment: @Billda That sounds like a config issue where Firebase Crashlytics isn't enabled for Release builds, but more information would be needed, so you may need to raise a new question or contact Firebase support.

Comment: Did you manage to fix it? @MikeBonnell

Comment: @Jordan there's been a few different variants and many changes over the past couple of months, a quick summary of where you're at would be helpful. If you'll need someone to look into the specifics of your project, then you can ask via the Firebase support portal.

Comment: I am using crashlytics in my android app. I have followed [this](https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics/install) guide for configuration. When I run the app I get the same error messages (Received null settings, skipping initialization and Cannot send reports. Settings are unavailable.) in my logcat and nothing is happening on my dashboard as well. @MikeBonnell

Comment: Thanks, do you see the app present at all in the Fabric dashboard?

Comment: yes i can the app in the dashboard but the crashes aren't showing. @MikeBonnell

Comment: Gothca, I'd ping support(at)fabric(dot)io with your app's package name or bundle id.

Comment: I had the same thing for an app that was in Fabric and I was updating it to use Crashlytics in Firebase. I decided I didn't need the data in Fabric so deleted the app from their dashboard. It then started working in Firebase with no problems.

Answer (score 4):

You need to link your project to Fabric. Ignore it if you already did it. Else follow these steps

[image]
[image]

It will navigate to Fabric and follow the instructions (create an account or sign in if you already have an account). After successfully logged in to the Fabric, Next you have to link your project to Fabric for that you can use the Fabric plugin.

[image]

After installing the plugin you can open it by clicking either of the below options shown below.

[image]

And follow instructions to create the Fabric project.After that from the firebase console -> Crashlytics -> link your firebase project to Fabric project.

That's all...

Answer (score 4):

When upgrading from Fabric Crashlytics to Firebase Crashlytics I found that I needed to make sure that `AndroidManifest.xml` contained this attribute from Fabric. After having correctly linked the App in Fabric with Firebase. Which you can find at https://www.fabric.io/settings/organizations,

```
<meta-data
    android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
    android:value="..." />
```

(Replacing `...` with your key)
This needs to be within the `<application>` block. Once I included this the settings were detected and crashes appeared in the Firebase console, email alerts.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this same error occurred because i already had forced the crash on the device as required by setup [tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?authuser=0), for a different flavor of the application.

My App has 2 flavors, so in order to successfully link flavor number 2 i had to force crash on a different simulator.

Note: The 2 flavors need to have different packages at least.

Answer (score 0):

Same happened to me. I had another flavor of the app installed, so I deleted all flavors currently installed and it worked after simulating the crash again.

Answer (score 0):

Tried all the above answers and other SO answers none of them worked for me. After spending few hours find the reason. You should give right dependencies.

Step 1: Add plugin in app level gradle (same order)

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
}
```

Step 2: Crashlytics dependency (app level)

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics'
```

Step 3: Project level

```
    classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.2'
```

Step 4: Initialize in your application onCreate()

```
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(getApplicationContext());
```