# Failed to retrieve settings from crashlitics

Tags: android, crashlytics

I wanted to upgrade to Firebase Crashlytics from Firebase Crash. I followed this tutorial: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?authuser=0

but I get this:

> 04-03 15:26:10.403 1770-1908/org.odk.collect.android E/Fabric: Failed
>   to retrieve settings from
>   https://settings.crashlytics.com/spi/v2/platforms/android/apps/org.odk.collect.android/settings
>   04-03 15:26:10.403 1770-1912/org.odk.collect.android E/Answers: Failed
>   to retrieve settings 04-03 15:26:56.973
>   1770-1926/org.odk.collect.android W/CrashlyticsCore: Cannot send
>   reports. Settings are unavailable.

I found this questions: [Crashlytics says "Received null settings, skipping report submission"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47199793/crashlytics-says-received-null-settings-skipping-report-submission?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

and the answer that I should open https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/optin/devsummit and enable Crashlitics. The problem here is when I open the link I see a button "Let me in" and every time I click on that button I get:

> Something went wrong. You may already have access. Please refresh and
>   try again.

The first time I clicked on the button I got a message like:

> It should be available in 5 minutes

or something like that (I can't recall).

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Mike from Firebase here. For this, it's best to contact Firebase or Fabric support so we can dive into your specific situation.

Comment: Eventually, I was able to finish the configuration changing my build variant. I still don't know what was wrong since I have Crashlitics enabled for both but never mind it works.

Comment: did you solve this issue?